# How to check if the smartphone has gyroscope in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I'm using the *Google Cardboard SDK*. In older versions of *Google Cardboard SDK*, it included a file named *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="true"/>
```

So a solution could be to simple add that file back to my project.

However I don't like it because if I do it, the app is hidden in Google Play if the device doesn't have a gyroscope, and that's confusing for the users because they tend to search for it in Google Play.

So, how can I check if the device has a gyroscope from the code to show a message to the user like: this smartphone does have gyroscope. Please try with another smartphone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if there is a gyro sensor on the device with `Input.isGyroAvailable`

```
if (Input.isGyroAvailable)
{
    //Gyro is available
}
```

That's now deprecated and should be used for really old version of Unity. For newer version of Unity, use [`SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-supportsGyroscope.html).

```
if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
{
    //Gyro is available
}
```